# Understanding c++ new operator

Tags: c++, new-operator

Assume that ITEM is a class

```
ITEM* items = new ITEM[10];
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    new(&items[i)ITEM();
new(&items[0])ITEM(items[1]);
```

Is the above valid?

The way I understand it is that the last 2 uses of the new operator
do not allocate memory. They just invoke the constructor of ITEM.

Is the above equivalent to?

```
ITEM* items = new ITEM[10];
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    items[i] = ITEM();
item[0] = ITEM(items[1]);
```

EDIT:

https://github.com/gosom/practice-cpp/blob/master/arrays/darray.h

I use it here (for practicing)

Comment: No, it's not equivalent, but a more detailed explanation depends on how is `ITEM` defined. Can you show its definition?

Comment: It sure doesn't look valid to me. There are multiple parse errors that I cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: ITEM can be a primitive type or a user defined type.
The above can be used in a container.

Comment: @gosom, it better not be used in a container. A container template is best when valid for all types, and as such must carefully differentiate between raw memory and constructed objects.

Comment: I think your confusion stems from not understanding the difference between `operator new`, which is a function that does memory allocation. And the *new operator*, which is an expression that allocates & constructs objects in memory.

Comment: @StoryTeller totally agree

Comment: You could find out if they're equivalent by overloading the default constructor, the assignment operator, the copy constructor, and the destructor and doing some logging inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way I understand it is that the last 2 uses of the new operator do not allocate memory. They just invoke the constructor of ITEM.

Yes. This is the "placement new" operator, wich does not allocate memory and calls object constructor. This is legal to proceed the way you do, though `ITEM` constructor will be called twice (meaning that the `ITEM` class constructor will be executed twice: one when standard `new` is called, one when placement `new` is called). This may lead to memory leak (or other unexpected behavior) if some ressources are allocated in `ITEM`'s constructor. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) for more info about placement new.

> Is the above equivalent to?

No, this is not equivalent. In the latter case, you create a temporary object at each loop, which you copy to `item[i]`. This will call `ITEM` constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, at each loop. In the previous situation, placement new only calls `ITEM` constructor, nothing else.

The typical usage of "placement new" is when you want your object to be allocated in a specific memory area (instead of the heap, where standard `new` operator allocates memory). This may be shared memory or so... "Placement new" is one of the few situations where the object destructor can/must be called explicitely, i.e.: `item[i]->~ITEM()`

Comment: Ok, I am a bit confused. Also @StoryTeller mentioned the double construction.
Can you explain a bit more or point me to a document explaining this?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    new(&items[i)ITEM();
```

The above is potentially invalid. The `new` operator constructs each object in the array already. This is double construction (which can and probably will lead to errors for less than trivial types).

```
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    items[i] = ITEM();
```

This just assigns a default constructed object to each entry in the array. This is as safe as the assignment operator is.

In general placement `new` is supposed to be used on *raw* memory.

Comment: This is not necessarily right, which is why I requested clarification on the question. If `ITEM` is a type for which it's safe to omit a destructor call, then in-place construction without first destroying the original object doesn't have to be a problem, and can even make sense.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/
in the example line 22:
// does not allocate memory -- calls: operator new (sizeof(MyClass),p2)
      // but constructs an object at p2

Comment: @hvd, phrasing adjusted.

Comment: @gosom, this is an awful example. cpluplus is in many ways an inferior reference IMO. Try [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) instead.

Comment: Can I do that:
   f(or i=0;i<10;++i)
       new(&items[i])

does it invokes constructor?

Comment: @gosom, it's invalid syntax. So you can't do that.